# Concat parameter syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, concatenation

Not sure how to even ask the question, if any suggestions for the title please let me know...

I have the following function that retrieves via AJAX information of a JSON file. This function as you can see below:

```
setOptionsSettings("[data-machine-brand-options]", apiUrlMachineBrands, 'name');

function setOptionsSettings(htmlElement, url, apiParameter) {

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        // CREATE GENERIC SOLUTION for the spinner
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            $('main').html('<div class="spinner"><div class="hori-verti-centering"><div class="bounce bounce1"></div><div class="bounce bounce2"></div><div class="bounce bounce3"></div></div></div>');
            setHeader(xhr);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(i) {
                $(htmlElement).append("<option id=" + data[i].id + " value=" + data[i].apiParameter + ">" + data[i].apiParameter + "</option>");
            });
        }
    });
    return {};
}
```

I'm trying to set `apiParamter` so when you call the function `setOptionSettings` you can place the name of the parameter you need to call. So in this case the parameter is `name`. How can I insert this into the function so it works?

I tried the following and other solutions but nothing would work, any suggestions?

```
$(htmlElement).append("<option id=" + data[i].id + " value=" + data[i]. + apiParameter + ">" + data[i]. + apiParameter + "</option>");
```

Comment: Why is there a dot after data[i] in "" value=" + data[i]." ?

Comment: data[i].id is working, that's how it should work. It selects a parameter. IN this case I have 'id' and 'name'. I want this function to be resused, so 'name' can be in another case 'surname' for example

Comment: what is htmlElement? is this id or class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access object property using string key use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) i.e `data[i][apiParameter]`

As you are using jQuery create element using it.

```
$(htmlElement).append($('<option></option>', {
    "id": data[i].id,
    "value": data[i][apiParameter]
}));
```

Comment: I find it almost dismaying that the original code contained `[i]` just fine, but still OP couldn't figure out `[apiParameter]`...

Comment: @Satpal This seems to work, but only the 'id' and 'value' are inserted. If I want it the same in between <option></option> What should I do? It does seem the correct way what you mean

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero, `"text": data[i][apiParameter]` You need to pass property values in constructor

Comment: @Satpal Where do you find this information? Really useful! Your answer solved my question

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero you can access to properties with literal object style or with array style. This: `var.prop.subprop` is the same as `var[prop][subprop]`. When you need to put variables in the object notation you must to change the syntax to an array access.